# Ramanujan Proof of Bertrand Postulate, first step

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, distribution-of-primes

Here is a link to his proof: http://www.zyymat.com/ramanujans-proof-of-bertrands-postulate.html.

I understand the first two "steps", that
$$\vartheta(x)=\log2+\log3+\ldots+\log p$$
where $p$ is the greatest prime less than or equal to $x$. Step two is that
$$\psi(x)=\vartheta(x)+\vartheta(x^{1/2})+\vartheta(x^{1/3})+\ldots$$
And then I read that 
$$\begin{align}\log(\lfloor x\rfloor !)&=\vartheta(x)+\vartheta(x^{1/2})+\vartheta(x^{1/3})+\ldots\\
&+\vartheta(\frac 12 x)+\vartheta(\frac 12 x^{1/2})+\vartheta(\frac 12x^{1/3})+\ldots\\
&+\vartheta(\frac 13 x)+\vartheta(\frac 13 x^{1/2})+\vartheta(\frac 13x^{1/3})+\ldots\\
&+\ldots
\end{align}$$
And I was like "Woah!!! Where did that come from?!"
**So where does it come from?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider  the [Von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function) $\Lambda$ which satisfies the following identities
$$\psi(x):=\sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda(n)=\ln(\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots\lfloor x\rfloor))\quad\text{and}\quad
\ln(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\Lambda(d)$$
where $\psi(x)$ is the so-called [second Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function).
Then
\begin{align}\exp\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\vartheta(x^{1/k})\right)&=\prod_{k\geq 1}\exp\left(\vartheta(x^{1/k})\right)=\prod_{k\geq 1}\prod_{p\leq x^{1/k}}p\\
&=\prod_{k\geq 1}\prod_{p^k\leq x}p=\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots\lfloor x\rfloor)=\exp(\psi(x))
\end{align}
where $\vartheta(x):=\sum_{p\leq x}\ln(p)$ is the so-called [first Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function).
Moreover
\begin{align}\log(\lfloor x\rfloor !)&=\sum_{n\leq x} \ln(n)=\sum_{n\leq x} \sum_{d\mid n}\Lambda(d)\\
&=\sum_{dk\leq x} \Lambda(d)=\sum_{k\leq x}\sum_{d\leq x/k} \Lambda(d)\\
&=\sum_{1\leq k\leq x}\psi(x/k)=\sum_{k\geq 1}\psi(x/k).
\end{align}

Comment: Why does $$\psi(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda(n)$$?

Comment: @D.R. This is the definition of the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function